# How to run emulambda on windows

Tags: python, windows, aws-lambda

how to run emulambda on windows?

when I run this on cmd:

```
 emulambda -v application.lambda_handler test/test-event.json
```

I got this error:

> 'emulambda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>        operable program or batch file.

Comment: seems like you need to install emulambda.

Comment: @Jim I did install emulambda, but when I tried to use the emulambda, i got that error.